# Matching one-line JavaScript comments (//) with re

Tags: javascript, python, regex, replace

I'd like to filter out (mostly one-line) comments from (mostly valid) JavaScript using python's `re` module. For example:

```
// this is a comment
var x = 2 // and this is a comment too
var url = "http://www.google.com/" // and "this" too
url += 'but // this is not a comment' // however this one is
url += 'this "is not a comment' + " and ' neither is this " // only this
```

I'm now trying this for more than half an hour without any success. Can anyone please help me?

**EDIT 1**:

```
foo = 'http://stackoverflow.com/' // these // are // comments // too //
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
bar = 'http://no.comments.com/'
```

Comment: At this point, you should consider using a proper parser instead of trying to hack up a regex.

Comment: Thanks Anon., if I can't come up with a regex soon I'll go for a parser. SpiderMonkey perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My regex powers had gone a bit stale so I've used your question to fresh what I remember.
It became a fairly large regex mostly because I also wanted to filter multi-line comments.

```
import re

reexpr = r"""
    (                           # Capture code
        "(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"       # String literal
        |
        '(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'       # String literal
        |
        (?:[^/\n"']|/[^/*\n"'])+ # Any code besides newlines or string literals
        |
        \n                      # Newline
    )|
    (/\*  (?:[^*]|\*[^/])*   \*/)        # Multi-line comment
    |
    (?://(.*)$)                 # Comment
    $"""
rx = re.compile(reexpr, re.VERBOSE + re.MULTILINE)
```

This regex matches with three different subgroups. One for code and two for comment contents.
Below is a example of how to extract those.

```
code = r"""// this is a comment
var x = 2 * 4 // and this is a comment too
var url = "http://www.google.com/" // and "this" too
url += 'but // this is not a comment' // however this one is
url += 'this "is not a comment' + " and ' neither is this " // only this

bar = 'http://no.comments.com/' // these // are // comments
bar = 'text // string \' no // more //\\' // comments
bar = 'http://no.comments.com/'
bar = /var/ // comment

/* comment 1 */
bar = open() /* comment 2 */
bar = open() /* comment 2b */// another comment
bar = open( /* comment 3 */ file) // another comment 
"""

parts = rx.findall(code)
print '*' * 80, '\nCode:\n\n', '\n'.join([x[0] for x in parts if x[0].strip()])
print '*' * 80, '\nMulti line comments:\n\n', '\n'.join([x[1] for x in parts if x[1].strip()])
print '*' * 80, '\nOne line comments:\n\n', '\n'.join([x[2] for x in parts if x[2].strip()])
```

Comment: Wow, this is even one step ahead of the question, but this is exactly what I need! Thank you very much for taking your time to solve this problem!

Comment: I edited the regex because it didn't match '*' like in 'x = 4 * 5', which became 'x = 4  5)'

Comment: Doesn’t work for `/* / */` or `/* // */`. Fix: Replace `/\\*  (?:\\*?[^/]|\n)*  \\*/` with `/\\*  (?:[^*]|\\*[^/])*  \\*/`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to parse if you had explicit semi-colons.

In any case, this works:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'.*(//(.*))$')

lines = ["// this is a comment", 
    "var x = 2 // and this is a comment too",
    """var url = "http://www.google.com/" // and "this" too""",
    """url += 'but // this is not a comment' // however this one is""",
    """url += 'this "is not a comment' + " and ' neither is this " // only this""",]

for line in lines: 
    print rx.match(line).groups()
```

---

Output of the above:

```
('// this is a comment', ' this is a comment')
('// and this is a comment too', ' and this is a comment too')
('// and "this" too', ' and "this" too')
('// however this one is', ' however this one is')
('// only this', ' only this')
```

---

I'm not sure what you're doing with the javascript *after* removing the comments, but [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) might help. It removes comments well enough anyway, and there is an [implementation in python](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.py.txt).

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a +1. Let me modify my question a bit now :)

Comment: Also, the JavaScript is not written by me, so unfortunately I can't guarantee the explicit semicolons...

Comment: Ehm, no, this will only work if there is always a comment at the end of the line, and when there's no // inside the comment itself. Both `var url = "http://www"` and `// comments are started with //` will fail.

Comment: @Thomas Well, it works for the specified inputs. As @Anon mentioned, a real parser is needed here to catch everything properly.

Comment: Thanks, the Python implementation of JSMin will fit my needs for now.